# Need help in sql query to find sum of hours based on difference between columns in a single table based on column type in mysql

Tags: mysql

At present we have a table in mysql with the following definition.

```
CREATE TABLE `tblStaffLog` ( 
`SlNo` Int( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`UserName` VarChar( 20 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`PageName` VarChar( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`LogType` VarChar( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Extension` VarChar( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`LogTime` DateTime NOT NULL,
`IPAddress` VarChar( 20 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`activity` VarChar( 20 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
`reason` VarChar( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( `SlNo` ) )
```

We need to calculate the total hours worked for a specific date and for this we need to subtract LogType column having value logout with the previous LogType column with Value LogIn. The sample rows for a day is listed below.

```
 SlNo    UserName   LogType     LogTime
355034  Krishna     LogIn   2018-04-01 08:02:32
355036  Krishna     LogOut  2018-04-01 08:50:28
355041  Krishna     LogIn   2018-04-01 09:19:31
355048  Krishna     LogOut  2018-04-01 10:03:16
355051  Krishna     LogIn   2018-04-01 10:12:12
355060  Krishna     LogOut  2018-04-01 11:07:48
355064  Krishna     LogIn   2018-04-01 11:20:01
355072  Krishna     LogOut  2018-04-01 12:33:52
355073  Krishna     LogIn   2018-04-01 12:35:19
355082  Krishna     LogOut  2018-04-01 13:10:02
355083  Krishna     LogIn   2018-04-01 13:14:07
355098  Krishna     LogOut  2018-04-01 17:02:06
```

How to write a sql query to get the total hours worked for the day

Comment: we can say that there will be always log out after log in during a day?

Comment: yes there will be a logout after a login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub query to get the logout associated with the login and some date functions to sum the hours worked. The query below illustrates how this works you could rejig it to make it more efficient if you wish.

```
drop table if exists t;

CREATE TABLE `t` ( 
`SlNo` Int( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`UserName` VarChar( 20 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`LogType` VarChar( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`LogTime` DateTime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( `SlNo` ) );
insert into t (username,logtype,logtime) values
( 'Krishna'  ,   'LogIn'  , '2018-04-01 08:02:32'),
('Krishna'  ,   'LogOut' , '2018-04-01 08:50:28'),
('Krishna'  ,   'LogIn'  , '2018-04-01 09:19:31'),
('Krishna'  ,   'LogOut' , '2018-04-01 10:03:16'),
( 'Krishna'  ,   'LogIn'  , '2018-05-01 08:02:32'),
( 'Krishna'  ,   'LogOut' , '2018-05-01 08:50:28'),
( 'Krishna'  ,   'LogIn'  , '2018-05-01 09:19:31'),
( 'Krishna'  ,   'LogOut' , '2018-05-01 10:03:16'),
( 'bob'  ,   'LogIn'  , '2018-05-01 08:02:32'),
( 'bob'  ,   'LogOut' , '2018-05-01 08:50:28'),
( 'bob'  ,   'LogIn'  , '2018-05-01 09:19:31'),
( 'bob'  ,   'LogOut' , '2018-05-01 15:03:16');

select username, dt, sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(hrsworked)))
from
(
select  username, date(logtime) dt,logtime logintime,
        (select t1.logtime from t t1 where t1.username = t.username and t1.logtime > t.logtime  and logtype = 'logout' order by logtime limit 1) logout,
      timediff(
        (select t1.logtime from t t1 where t1.username = t.username and t1.logtime > t.logtime  and logtype = 'logout' order by logtime limit 1) ,
        logtime) hrsworked
from t 
where logtype = 'login'
) s
group by username,dt
order by dt,username;

+----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| username | dt         | sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(hrsworked))) |
+----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| Krishna  | 2018-04-01 | 01:31:41                                 |
| bob      | 2018-05-01 | 06:31:41                                 |
| Krishna  | 2018-05-01 | 01:31:41                                 |
+----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```